# Why is a Node.js 12 docker app connection to MongoDB 4 via the docker network giving a timeout while a connection via the public network works?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, networking, meteor

I'm seeing a problem I can't explain at all:

After upgrading a Meteor app to v 1.9 and therefore Node.js 12 we also have to switch docker containers to Node.js 12 based containers. In our case we use [abernix/meteord:node-12-base](https://hub.docker.com/r/abernix/meteord) ([git](https://github.com/abernix/meteord)).

After booting up the updated app we get a DB timeout in the docker container of the app:

```
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                                               throw(ex);
                                               ^

MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 10000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/topology.js:773:16)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

This happens with the following `MONGO_URL`:

> ❌ mongodb://root:OurPw@**mongo-docker-alias**:27017/meteor?authSource=admin

Funnily enough when we expose the port 27017 in the MongoDB container the following `MONGO_URL` just works:

> ✔️ mongodb://root:OurPw@**docker-host**:27017/meteor?authSource=admin

Now I thought we are having a docker problem but if I attach to a bash inside the Node.js 12 meteord container, apt install the MongoDB shell and try to connect with:

> ✔️ mongo "mongodb://root:OurPw@**mongo-docker-alias**:27017/meteor?authSource=admin"

that also just works.

And now I'm left without a clue. I tried multiple MongoDB docker images between v4.0 and 4.2.3 as well as Node.js 12.14 and 12.10. And I also tried without MongoDB auth one time just to rule it out as the problem but the outcome is always the same.

Any idea would be very much appreciated since I'd like to avoid having to connect via an exposed port and the docker host's name because that is prone to errors obviously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **tl;dr:**

setting `dns_search: ''` for the backend in the `docker-compose.yml` (or via the [docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) or other means) fixes the problem.

### More information:

Docker seems to add any `search` directive of the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` to the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` per default. However resolving something like `mongo-docker-alias.actual-intranet-domain.tld` is likely to be problematic since the outside network and DNS has no knowledge of this subdomain. Actually we found out that it got still resolved inside the container in our case, it just took a few seconds (vs <1ms normally). And since the backend tries to establish multiple DB connection it always runs into the timeout.

[Docker's DNS search option](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) luckily allows to divert from the default behavior including setting a blank value. Knowing the problem another workaround should be to use docker aliases with a dot in it since then the `search` shouldn't be used, but we haven't tried that.

A few questions remain but they are not so important. Like in our case why did this happen with the Meteor update, maybe the actual reason was that also the docker version on the host changed since we wouldn't be aware of an infrastructure change. And in general why is docker adding these entries to `/etc/resolv.conf`? It doesn't seem very useful but if it is maybe there is in general a better approach for this?

A very helpful blog post on this matter was also published by [davd.io](https://www.davd.io/docker-mongodb-connection-slow/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the /etc/mOngd.conf file for the network binding. You may need to allow it to respond on all network interfaces as the network might be a different ip/subnet when exposed (or not) which might explain why it works in some scenarios

Comment: afik the docker mongo image does not use a `mongod.conf` and in fact there is none at `/etc/mongod.conf` so it should use defaults. Also if the problem would be here the connection with the mongo shell from the app container to mongo container and interface like described above would not work or am I wrong?

Comment: I use standalone server for my mongo cluster. Docker networking can be tricky to debug. I’ve had issues in the past where the dns refused to resolvethe name but you say thar your mongoshell command is working. 

My only other thought then is are you really sure that meteor is getting the correct mongo_url passed to it? Could there be a typo? I echo out the mongourl in my docker startup script just to be sure that it is set.